# How to convert pdf to excel ? using python anaconda code

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried pdf to excel conversion using python, 
but it converts only table to excel ,
not the text inside the pdf.
So what is the exact code to convert any pdf to excel ? whether it contains any text related informations and also table related information.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: import tabula
import os
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\AK370953\Desktop')
tabula.convert_into('sample.pdf','Output1.csv',output_format='csv',pages='all

Comment: The above code converts only table which is inside the pdf to excel. i need to convert the whole pdf to excel whether it contains any text related information or table..

Comment: You are talking about OCR processing. I think its not that straight forward to convert to excel any way. How would you place your text int a excel?

Answer (score 1):

I am the Product Manager for PDFTables. The following code is an example of using Python to extract text and table information from PDFs: https://github.com/pdftables/python-pdftables-api

```
import pdftables_api

c = pdftables_api.Client('my-api-key')
c.xlsx('input.pdf', 'output.xlsx')
```